# LinqPad Feature - Does VS do this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linq, linqpad

Linqpad, when coding in C#, will draw a vertical line between opening and closing curly braces.

Boy, oh boy, I sure do wish Visual Studio would do this. Does it? Is there anyway to make it do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[CodeRush Xpress for C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/dd218053.aspx) will do that, and MS is providing it for free.

Comment: Freaking love SO - Programming for years now and never heard of this - Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Get the [CodeRush tools](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) - they do what you want and more.

Comment: Beware, the Coderush express tools crash on invalid LINQ. I don't know why but I had to uninstall it because if I made a typo during a LINQ query, VS would hang and crash.

Comment: "for free" - Looks like it's only free as an evaluation.. am i missing something?

Comment: CodeRush does not crash on my invalid linq.

Answer (score 1):

CodeRush is the truth...